# jQuery draggable: access the being-dragged element on drag start

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to modify the element when as soon as it starts being dragged. The 'start' callback takes two arguments, only the first of them seems to be usable for me. The deal is that I'm using `helper: 'clone'`  which makes `event.originalTarget` to point only the "original" element, not the new one (which is in fact the one being dragged).
Any solutions?
Thanks,
m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't `ui.helper` what you need? From the docs:

> ui.helper - the jQuery object representing the helper that's being dragged

So you'll have something like

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
   start: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.modify(the_way_I_want_to_modify_it);
   }
});
```

Comment: not really. ui.helper points the `ul` element, while the one I'm dragging is it's `li`

Comment: Could you make an example using http://jsFiddle.net? Maybe the `ul` you see is a new `ul` created by jQuery to hold the `li` that's being dragged. (You can't have a `li` outside an `ul`.)